# Project ignores build.gradle when cloned from Git

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, gitlab

First of all I've got a Java Project with Spring boot and I'm using Gradle.

My Problem is, when I am cloning my Project from Gitlab the spring framework libraries aren't working. On every import statement the following occurs:

```
Unused import statements
```

I figured out how to fix it. I only need to copy the content of my whole `build.gradle` file, delete the content and paste it in the build.gradle file again. After this step everything works normal.

my `build.gradle` looks as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Is there a better way of fixing this issue than copy and paste?

Comment: I didn't understand what you copy&paste to get rid of which problem. Can you elaborate a bit more clearly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but even with your update I still don't understand what you did.

Comment: Compare the binary content (e.g. with a hex editor) of the file before and after to find out what is different.